# Installing APK app on Android Without Market

Tags: android, google-play

Is it possible to install an APK to your android without using the android market?

I am talking about enterprise applications here, so would rather have the app private rather than allowing everyone to install it from the market.

How about the option 'Unknown sources' on the phone, does that mean installing an unsigned app (if it is indeed possible to build and use an unsigned app) or is that allowing installing an app from outside the android market?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you enable Unknown Sources on the phone, you can download any APK via a URL and open it, which will cause it to be installed.

Comment: Thanks, that is what I wanted to know. But in an enterprise setting this seems a bit unprofessional to ask people to enable that option. Are there any enterprise schemes for android? For instance iOS has an enterprise licensing and distribution option.

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

All apps need  to be signed for the application to be installed. Unknown sources is used to install app from outside android market like copy to sdcard and then install.